# how to embed an SVG in Angular material button

Tags: angular, angular-material

looking to embed SVG as the icon for a button,
something in the sorts of:

```
<button mat-raised-button class="containerSideButton" type="button" (click)="onInfo()">
        <svg id="person" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path d="M12 5.9c1.16 0 2.1.94 2.1 2.1s-.94 2.1-2.1 2.1S9.9 9.16 9.9 8s.94-2.1 2.1-2.1m0 9c2.97 0 6.1 1.46 6.1 2.1v1.1H5.9V17c0-.64 3.13-2.1 6.1-2.1M12 4C9.79 4 8 5.79 8 8s1.79 4 4 4 4-1.79 4-4-1.79-4-4-4zm0 9c-2.67 0-8 1.34-8 4v3h16v-3c0-2.66-5.33-4-8-4z" />
        </svg>
    </button>
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Try adding `width` or `min-width` style for button.

Comment: I feel you need add "width" to your svg: `<svg .... width="16"..>`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button
    mat-menu-item
    (click)="delete();"
  >
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon> DELETE
  </button>
```

You can make your own components with `<mat-icon>`

"delele" keyword inside of `<mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>` is the way to call to delete svg icon

Of course you need to angular material in your `package.json`

Please read the docs:

https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview